# Mouse highlight lines issue, root cause of data deletion / messed up

Tags: terminal

[https://gofile.io/d/zA8QPs]video of vim highlight issue[1](https://gofile.io/d/zA8QPs)

I like vim a lot, the stability is wonderful.. However there is 1 protection feature that i need to have most.

I am used to use vim with both mouse and keyboard (i found it is beneficial to me).
Mouse is mostly used to highlight and middle click to paste the highlighted content and simple scroll.. it is a good feature.

However, i often did this mistake. I used mouse to highlight the content but (still in highlight mode) forgot to exit the highlight mode and page up/dw (or jump to other location) in this manner. This causes the highlight (instead of supposedly highlight only 2 lines) mode to highlight all the lines (more than i intended) till the place where i jumped to to be either deleted/ pasted/ copied (depend on my command).
This causes major data damage/ lost so far (for me).

Sometime i just want to highlight (use mouse) to few lines, then scroll up a bit to paste (middle button of mouse) those lines  there.. but when i scrolled up  i forgot to stop the highlight mode.. and i pasted more lines of data that i intended to, hence causing confusion and mess. Worst case: deleted too many lines of data then i intended, because of scrolling in highlight mode.

Is there way to overcome this issue ?
Thanks.
Edited:
[image: example of scrolling within screen]
[image: scrolling outside of screen]

Yes, i understand, because i am having trouble in expressing it. .Don't know how to express it in word.. LOL I only use terminal vim (even though i have installeg Gvim) When i scroll in vim, mostly i use scroll button of mouse.

Try to use mouse (left click) to start highlight text .. then just scroll the page using "scroll roller of mouse". As long as you scroll the page only a bit, as long as the carret didn't get "dragged" out of screen, your highlighted text will be the same.

However, when you scroll too much, the carret will scrolled to the edge of the screen and when further scrolling, it will "drags" the carret on the edge of screen, and hence highlight more lines and more (depend on how much you scroll) or the highlighted text will become "unhighlighted" and the lines another side (of initially highlighted lines) will become highlighted more and more (depend on how much you scroll in the direction). –

So as i said, I often accidentally highlight (during scrolling), and then i press a paste or delete or substitute..etc cmd.. Hence all "accidentally highlighted text" all either deleted or being paste into somewhere it is not suppose to..hence messed up my data. This is one of my Most annoying issue which i don't know how to look for solution.

I often thought why nobody else ever mention of this annoying issue ?

[https://gofile.io/d/zA8QPs]video of vim highlight issue[1](https://gofile.io/d/zA8QPs)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what is going on here... When you're scrolling, are you using the scrollbar (in GVim) or the mouse wheel? Is that extending the selection or leaving it out of screen? Is the problem that when you're pasting (with middle button) Vim is *replacing* the selection, which you don't see because it's off screen? Or something else? Can you please [edit] the post to give a few more details? It would also help to know more about your environment... (GVim or Vim on a terminal? Which O.S.? etc.) This actually matters for scroll behavior!

Comment: Yes, i understand, because i am having trouble in expressing it. .Don't know how to express it in word.. LOL
I only use terminal vim (even though i have installeg Gvim)
When i scroll in vim, mostly i use scroll button of mouse.

Comment: Try to use mouse (left click) to start highlight text .. then just scroll the page using "scroll roller of mouse". As long as you scroll the page only a bit, as long as the carret didn't get "dragged" out of screen, your highlighted text will be the same.

Comment: I have added 2 photos above, hopefully that explained better..

Comment: So, is there such problem with other people who uses vim terminal with mouse ? 
i hope i am not alone..

Comment: @filbranden Hii, i have upload a video of the issue. Please take a look. Thankjs